# Symfony2 FR3DLdapBundle with FOSUserBundle update user

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, fr3dldapbundle

I couldn't find any answer on the web for my question so I sign up to this fantastic forum.

Here is my problem.

I have a Symfony2 project with FOSUserBundle and FR3DLdapBundle to log in with Active Directory.

Everything works fine, I have the log form, when I try to log it check to the AD, retreive the User and insert him in my DB.

To do this I follow :
http://blog.henriet.eu/authentification-ldap-avec-symfony-2.1-et-fosuserbundle.html
and
http://prob6.com/fr/

If I log in a second time, it works BUT the user in my DB is not updated.

So my question is, FR3DldapBundle and FOSUserBundle insert the user at the first time but how to update him after ? 
Because between 2 connections some data could change in the Active Directory so I want my the user in my database updated ?

I thought about delete him at logout but not very clean...

So I hope somebody has the answer on how update user with FR3DLdap on FOSUser.

Thank you